# Render Queuing with Mac Terminal Shell

Tags: rendering, osx

I've recently learned how to render using the Mac Terminal Shell, which has been very useful to render an animation while I continue to work in the Blender workspace!

However, I might have a new Blender file a few moments later that I would like to render, and I would like to add it to a queue after the first job has fully rendered.

Is there a good shell method to add new jobs sequentially as I need them?

Comment: That sounds more like a Mac question than a Blender one so is really off-topic here.